# React-Native Placing Pressable above background Image

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, frontend

I have a background Image that I am placing overtop of all of my other elements.

> Screen

```
  ...other stuff...

  return (
    <View style={styles.body}>
          
        <FlatList
            style={styles.prizeList}
            data={TEST_DATA}
            numColumns={2}
            renderItem={({item, index}) => {
              let bgShelfImage = FULL_SHELF;

              if (index === TEST_DATA.length - 1) {
                bgShelfImage = FULL_SHELF;
              } else {
                if (index % 2 === 1) {
                  bgShelfImage = SECOND_HALF_SHELF;
                } else {
                  bgShelfImage = FIRST_HALF_SHELF;
                }
              }

              return (
                <PrizeShelfCard
                  prize={item}
                  bgShelfImage={bgShelfImage}
                  handleShowPrize={handleShowPrize}
                  handleDisplayPrizeTitleChange={handleDisplayPrizeTitleChange}
                  handleDisplayPrizeDescChange={handleDisplayPrizeDescChange}
                  handleDisplayPrizeTypeChange={handleDisplayPrizeTypeChange}
                  handleDisplayPrizeTierChange={handleDisplayPrizeTierChange}
                />
              );
            }}
            keyExtractor={item => item.prizeId}
          />
 
      <ImageBackground
        style={styles.backgroundContainer}
        source={bookshelf}
        resizeMode="stretch"
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  body: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#29211F',
  },
  backgroundContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
  },
  prizeList: {
    marginTop: hp('5%'),
    display: 'flex',
  },
});
```

> PrizeDisplayCard

```
  ...other stuff....

  return (
    <View style={styles.body}>
      <ImageBackground
        style={styles.backgroundContainer}
        source={shelfImage}
        resizeMode="stretch"
      />
      <Pressable
        style={styles.pressable}
        onPress={() => {
          console.log('prize clicked!');
        }}>
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  body: {
    flex: 1,
    height: hp('25%'),
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#29211F',
  },
  backgroundContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
  },
  pressable: {
    height: '50%',
    width: '50%',
    marginBottom: hp('5%'),
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  },
});
```

The problem is this. In the Screen code, I have an imageBackground which I place above all other elements. I need to do this because the background needs to overlay the other elements.

[image]

In this image, the outline of the "bookshelf" is this image:

[image]

overlayed and the rest is rendered by the flatlist since there will be a dynamic amount of elements. The red box is a pressable element. The pressable cannot be pressed because the Background template is overtop of the pressable. How can I make it so that the pressable is above the background Image? Is this possible the way that I'm doing it or do I need to find a different way?

I tried playing around with the zIndex, but that wasn't much help

##### Edit

Got rid of irrelevent parts of the code

Answer (score 1):

zIndex only works on ios. I assume thaty ou are using android, that you can use elevation instead ;)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am using android, but sadly this does not fix my problem

Comment: Why do you need your background to overlay the other stuff?

Comment: According to this thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31101445/in-react-native-how-do-i-put-a-view-on-top-of-another-view-with-part-of-it-lyi), you should be able to use absolute positioning for your overlaying elements; that should have the same effect

Comment: Because of some complications with the artwork. I  would need to show you the images, but basically, I have the bookshelf template (seen in the question) and then multiple shelf images. On each row, there ar e actually two images placed side by side, but it's done in such a way to not be noticeable. These images span from the left side to the right. If the background image is placed underneath the shelves, then you will notice the shelves spanning from left to right. Hopefully that makes sense, it's kinda hard to explain without showing you the images.

Comment: Oh, I think I missunderstood your problem. If you want to be able to click a button through an overlaying View, you can set the attribute pointerEvents to "none" inside the overlaying View (From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52775413/react-native-button-behind-transparent-view)

Comment: hmm, never heard of those before. Thanks for the info. But I just tried it and it won't work because the problem I that the ImageBacnground is overtop of the content. If it was possible to add pointerEvent="none" to the image background that would of solved my problem.

Comment: Ok, they I guess I either don't fully understand your problem or I just don't know any other solution. Sorry that I couldn't help you...

Comment: hey, thanks for the help. I'll give you an upvote for that. Since this isn't working, my backup solution is to chop up my image and change my layout, so I guess I'll be doing that.